# Outputting HTML in NodeJS is not working with res

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a DigitalOcean serverless function with but I am not sure how to output HTML - I can only get it to print to the console.

```
  const http = require('http');
  const url = require('url');

  const metascraper = require('metascraper')([
    require('metascraper-title')()
  ])

  const got = require('got');

 exports.main = (args) => {
   
  const targetUrl = "https://facebook.com";
   
   (async () => {
     
     res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
     
     try {

       const { body: html, url } = await got(targetUrl).catch(error => console.error(error));
       const metadata = await metascraper({ html, url }).catch(error => console.error(error));
       
       res.end("<h1>Print test</h1>");
       
       // Return the metadata as JSON
       console.log(JSON.stringify(metadata));
     } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   })()
   
   
 }
```

The error is that `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: res is not defined`

In the example provided by DigitalOcean, this is how they are able to output text:

```
exports.main = (args) => {
  return qrcode.toDataURL(args.text).then(res => ({
    headers:  { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' },
    body: args.img == undefined ? res : `<img src="${res}">`
  }))
}
```

I have tried using the `.then(res...` they also used in the example but that does not work either

How can I get text to be outputted to the document? I am not using express or anything, I just modified the example provided by DigitalOcean to get it to work with my own modules - this is a serverless function

Comment: @ITgoldman The `res.setHeader` causes an error too - so something to do with `res` being undefined

Comment: If I go by the example, what does `main` suppose to return? Maybe a function that returns {headers, body} ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is due ti the fact that you forgot to declare function arguments res. And you do not use qrcode.toDataURL that actually provides those response value. Also probably you mismatch request response with toDataURL function string response. It's different thing.
[image]